# Bootsrap is no properly diplaying-elements like jumbotron does not seem to be working

Tags: twitter-bootstrap-3, bootstrapping

I looked arround and I think I am using correctly the jumbotron element, but for some reason bootstrap is not working properly. I tried copy&pasting a working jumbotron from another page and it does not work here. Bootsrap css file is correctly connected because col-sm-6 is working properly. Thanks in advance!

P.S. style.css is an empty css file

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="es">
  <head>
     <meta charset="utf-8">
     <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
     <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
     <title>Lorem</title>
     <meta name="description" content="">
     <meta name="keywords" content="">
     <meta name="author" content="">

     <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"  href="./css/bootstrap.css">
     <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"  href="./css/style.css">
     <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"  href="./css/bootstrap-theme.css">
     <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"  href="./css/normalize.css">

     <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
     <script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
   </head>

  <body>
    <header></header>
    <div class="jumbotron login_main" >
        <div class="col-sm-6 vertical-center">
            <h1 class="text-center">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit</h1>
            <h2 class="text-center">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et</h2>
        </div>
        <form>
            <p>hello</p>
        </form>
    </div>
    <footer>

    </footer>   
  </body>
  </html>
```

Comment: How does it look like? How do you expect it to look like? Does the other page have additional CSS?

Comment: You have to have `row` class in your markup (before `col-sm-6`).

Answer (score 1):

```
    <div class="container">
        <div class="col-sm-6 col-sm-offset-3 vertical-center">
            <div class="jumbotron login_main" >
                <h1 class="text-center">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit</h1>
                <h2 class="text-center">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et</h2>
                <form>
                    <p>hello</p>
                </form>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

You're going to want to wrap it all in an element with the class "container". The bootstrap grid system uses 12 columns, so if you're going to have an element that is 6 columns wide, to center it, you'll need to offset it by 3. The code here should work.